Razorpay failed Payment, How to continue the payment?
I was making on a E-commerce website. In that I am using razorpay for payment integration.
If the payment was failed I will save it as pending in order's page, How can i continue the old failed payment.
Should I make a new order with the same amount for that or can i continue that payment with my old orderId??
If the payment is failed then I save the order id in the database with the order.

you can retry new payment with the old orderID

async function razorpay(orderId, productTotal, userId){
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var options = {
        "key": "rzp_test_key",
        "amount": productTotal*100,
        "currency": "INR",
        "order_id": orderId,
        "handler": function(response) {
          rzrPaymentAgain(" order is successful ");
        }
      };

      var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

      rzp1.on('payment.failed', async function(response) {
        console.log(response.error.metadata.order_id);
        console.log(response.error.metadata.payment_id);
      });

      rzp1.on('payment.error', function (response) {
        console.log('Payment error:', response.error);
      });

      rzp1.open();
    });
  }

when the order is failed we get an order id ( response.error.metadata.order_id ). we can save order and use it again to order.
If it once successful the payment, then you cannot use the order id to order again.
